# Raster image thresholding using python

Tags: python, raster, remote-sensing, digital-image-processing, feature-extraction

Can someone guide me for applying thresholding technique to input raster image using Python.

I intend to extract impervious surfaces from a high resolution raster such as roads, sideways and rooftops etc.

Comment: What type of imagery/data are you working with?

Comment: I am working with Google Earth imagery having spatial resolution of 0.5m.

Comment: Ok, so the imagery is not georeferenced (e.g. a screenshot in jpeg or png format)?

Comment: Aaron, It ain't a screenshot. It is in TIFF format (raster image) and has been georeferenced.

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "thresholding". Keeping data inbetween certain thresholds as masks? Have you produced any code so far which would clarify what you want?

Comment: Finally, do you have access to ArcGIS?

Comment: Kersten, so far I have been digging up to develop code but unable to. I intend to extract some impervious features for example "building rooftops" from satellite imagery using python code as a thresholding filter. You may say this "thresholding filter" may act as a mask to eliminate all other unwanted features except rooftops. I have come across edge extraction algorithm technique in QGIS but it doesn't yield desired results as Google Earth imagery is mosaiced/warped imagery already.

Comment: Yes, I do have ArcGIS with me Aaron.

Comment: My question is this,i tried below codes to change my RGB raster to binary raster in arcgis but it gives me error,how to correct this error >>>import cv2
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import arcpy
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> img = cv2.imread(r'C:\Try\New2017.tif',0)
>>> ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
>>> images = [img, thresh1]
>>> for i in xrange(2)... plt.subplot(1,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
... plt.title(titles[i])
... plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
... ... plt.show()
... Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)
>>>

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143843)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/143843)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [OpenCV](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_intro/py_intro.html) package in Python for [image thresholding](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html). This example shows not only how to perform the binary image thresholding, but also the limitations of this method. Here, I use a 1m spatial resolution NAIP image that shows a dirt road surrounded by arid vegetation. You can see that the road is extracted but there is also a significant amount of exposed soil and other background noise that is also extracted. There are a variety of [other thresholding methods](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html) available in OpenCV that you may want to investigate.

---

[image]

---

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Read the geotiff as greyscale image
img = cv2.imread(r'C:\your\path\roads_naip.tif',0)

# Apply the binary threshold. The second parameter "150" can be adjusted here.
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

titles = ['Original Image','Binary']
images = [img, thresh1]

for i in xrange(2):
    plt.subplot(1,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

Comment: This code works fine until inputting an image but on line ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img,139,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) it returns an ASSERTION ERROR like this,
error: (-215) m.dims >= 2 in function cv::Mat::Mat
I have tried to change the value of second parameter several times but the problem persists.

Comment: How are you running OpenCV? It is best to run cv2 via a distribution such as python(x,y).

Comment: Also, are you using 8-bit unsigned integer format rasters?

Comment: I am running OpenCV package in Enthought Python Distribution. Yes, the input TIFF RGB image is 8-bit unsigned integer raster having cell size (X,Y) = 0.5,0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thank you so much @Aaron. The problem has solved. I have realized that the above code needs to be slightly modified for the case of Google Earth imagery regarding its conversion to grey-scale intensity image. Following is the output of my modified code. Impervious surfaces of building rooftops have been extracted. Nevertheless, the results can be much improved through the combination of different thresholding techniques of OpenCV package.

[image: Applying image thresholding to Google Earth imagery]

Comment: @JibranKhan - You should consider accepting Aaron's solution by clicking the green-faded tick on the left-hand side of his post to show that this question has been answered :)

Comment: @Joseph: Done, though a bit late :) Thank you for guidance.

Comment: Most welcome buddy! And don't worry about being late =)